# Office365 Get ArchiveGuid through EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api, office365-apps

I am using this PowerShell commands to get the ArchiveGuid property from the Office:

```
PS > $O365Cred = (Get-Credential)
PS > New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/" -Credential $O365Cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
PS > Import-PSSession $session
PS > Get-Mailbox -Archive
PS > Get-Mailbox me@example.com |fl arch*
```

...and I get some useful data together with the ArchiveGuid property whose value is a nice looking GUID:

```
ArchiveDatabase     : NAMPR08DG002-db090
ArchiveGuid         : d9c4eced-a410-41a7-bbfe-ebfd7a1a3b2e
ArchiveName         : {In-Place Archive - my name}
ArchiveQuota        : 100 GB (107,374,182,400 bytes)
ArchiveWarningQuota : 90 GB (96,636,764,160 bytes)
ArchiveDomain       :
ArchiveStatus       : Active
ArchiveState        : Local
ArchiveRelease      :
```

But in my .NET app I want to get this GUID using EWS Managed API.

I tried translating the command above like this:

```
ExchangeService svc = new ExchangeService();
svc.Credentials = new WebCredentials("me@example.com", "password", "example.com");
svc.AutodiscoverUrl("me@example.com", MyAutodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
GetSearchableMailboxesResponse resp = svc.GetSearchableMailboxes("arch*", false);
```

but I get this error message:

```
The caller has not assigned any of the RBAC roles requested in the management role header
```

How can I pass this error? The PowerShell command works, what am I missing in my EWS call?